# Mysql query to get value like ab-123

Tags: mysql

I need a little help in queries.
I have a table like this:

```
id    value
1     rs-123
2     rsa-123
```

I need to get the first row if the user queries in following ways : rs123, rs-123, rs 123 (either using or skipping the space and dash).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(value, '-', ''), ' ', '')
    = REPLACE(REPLACE($val , '-', ''), ' ', '')
```

Comment: WHERE  replace(replace(value, '-',''), ' ', '') = replace(replace($val, '-', ''), ' ', '')

Comment: Fixed with this one, Thanks Rick for the  idea